# Django - Apache with mod_wsgi not serving static-files

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm using Apache with mod_wsgi to serve the project and it's static-files.

I used the offical docs ["How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and everything works fine, except the static files are not found. I haven't found any good way to debug that problem, or even get a specific message which could point me to the error.

What I did so far:

- double checked that the static-files are places correctly in the static-files directory. They were collected by *collectstatic*
- checked file permissions

**settings.py:**

```
[..]
DEBUG = False
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/djangoProject/static-files'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Apache Settings:**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess djangoProject

WSGIProcessGroup djangoProjectGroup
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIPythonHome /var/www/djangoProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/djangoProject/

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djangoProject/djangoProject/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/djangoProject/djangoProject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /var/www/djangoProject/static-files/
<Directory  /var/www/djangoProject/static-files>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/djangoProject')
sys.path.append('/var/www/djangoProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoProject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Apache Access Log:**

```
"GET /static/app01/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 346 "http://example.com/"
```

**apache2.conf:**

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/
```

Comment: How are you loading your apache conf? can you show your main httpd.conf?

Comment: I included the main apache2.conf

Comment: Unrelated to static files, but how you are setting up Python virtual environment is messed up a bit. Ensure you read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for correct way of doing it.

Comment: What do you get when you run ``ls -las /var/www/djangoProject/static-files``.

Comment: It shows the "app01" and "admin" directories

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the great Answer "[Serving static files with mod_wsgi and Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/732692/1167012)".

- The order is relevant, the Alias for static files **must** be in first place.

**Apache settings:**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess djangoProject

WSGIProcessGroup djangoProjectGroup
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIPythonHome /var/www/djangoProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/djangoProject/

Alias /static/ /var/www/djangoProject/static-files/
<Directory /var/www/djangoProject/static-files>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djangoProject/djangoProject/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/djangoProject/djangoProject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: thank you !. for posting this.. my problem was not to double check my document root, for 8 hours trying to fix it.. however this was a big help..

Comment: Saved my day! Thank You!